# Passing value <a> to decorator

Tags: python, html, flask, href

Im just learning Python, I' using Flask and I have a problem:
I try to pass values from one page to my decorator, but this value comes from  and this does not have name property.
This is my html:

```
<table border="4">
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Autor</td>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>Genre</td>
    <td>Excluir</td>
    <td>Actualizar</td>
</tr>
{% for album in listalbumes %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ album._id }}</td>
    <td>{{ album.name }}</td>
    <td><a href="/artist/{{ album.autor }}" id="autor" >{{ album.autor }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ album.year }}</td>
    <td>{{ album.name_genre }}</td>
    <td><a href="/excluir/{{ album._id }}">X</a></td>
    <td><a href="/actualizar/{{ album._id }}">Actualizar</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I try to pass {{ album.autor }} with the id, but I can't. And this is my py code:

```
@app.route('/artist/<string:autor>',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def artista(autor):
    autor = request.form.get("autor")
    alb = db.session.query(Album._id, Album.name, Album.autor, Album.year, 
    Album.media, Album.continent).filter(Album.autor == autor).all()
    if request.method == "GET":

        for g in alb:
            print("Album {} skill points.".format(g)) # testing db values, It works if I set manually values

        if alb:
            return render_template("artist.html", alb=alb)
```

Please, I hope anyone can help me
best Regards

Answer (score 0):

In your view/template you're trying to iterate through `listalbumes` but I don't see that being passed anywhere.

So I think you need to pass album list in some way like this:

```
@app.route('/artist/<string:autor>',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def artista(autor):
    autor = request.form.get("autor")

    if request.method == "GET": # Handle GET request
        alb = db.session.query(Album._id, Album.name, Album.autor, Album.year,
                               Album.media, Album.continent).filter(Album.autor=autor)

        if alb.exists(): # Handle if matching album list exists
            return render_template("artist.html", {"listalbumes": alb})
        else: # Handle if matching albumlist is not found
            return render_template("artist.html", {"listalbumes": []})

    else: # Handle POST request
        Album.create(autor)
        return Response("Created", status=201)
```

Comment: Thanks Umair, but my problem is that alb variable is null, because "Album.autor == autor" in the query does not take page href value. So alb is false or not exists

Comment: Can you please check the value of autor before using it in the filter ? and also do re-confirm that there should be single = or double == in filter , my guess is there should be single =.

Comment: Hi Umair, When I try to retrieve that value I got this:
"The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."

Comment: My problem is the <a> href, does not have "name" property, So I try to retrieve the value from id, but In does not work.

Comment: You're not handling POST request and also blank album list(Maybe pass a empty list ?). You should handle these too.

Answer (score 0):

I send value using button, with a url with parameters:

```
<table border="4">
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Autor</td>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>Genre</td>
    <td>Excluir</td>
    <td>Actualizar</td>
</tr>
{% for album in listalbumes %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ album._id }}</td>
    <td>{{ album.name }}</td>
    <!-- <td><a href="/artist/{{ album.autor }}"id="autor" >{{ album.autor }}</a></td> -->  <!-- esta vaina no funciona.... no se por que -->
    <!-- para que funcione enviamos los datos -->
    <td><input type="submit" value="{{ album.autor }}" name="autor" onclick="window.location.href='/artist/artist?autor={{ album.autor }}'" /></td>
    <td>{{ album.year }}</td>
    <td>{{ album.name_genre }}</td>
    <td><a href="/excluir/{{ album._id }}">X</a></td>
    <td><a href="/actualizar/{{ album._id }}">Actualizar</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In my code I get the value with  "request.args.get"

```
@app.route('/artist/<string:autor>',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def artista(autor):
if request.method == "GET":
    print('Im in GET')
    # autor = request.form.get("autor")
    autor = request.args.get('autor')
    print ("Autor=> ", autor)
```

Thanks for your helping!
        alb = db.session.query(Album._id, Album.name, Album.autor, Album.year, Album.media, Album.continent).filter(Album.autor == autor).all()
        for g in alb: 
            print("Album {} skill points.".format(g)) # testing db values

```
    return render_template("artist.html", autor=autor, alb=alb)
```